# goroutine split strategy

Tags: go, real-time, goroutine

In a real-time project, I have a standard event based front-end service received messages from and message queue broker. This service is designed to provide few others with relevant information.
Basically, this service loops on reception method, unmarshal the packet (protobuf for instance), update/control few parameters, marshal into another format (JSON for instance), then push to the next service.

The questions is: how to fire goroutine for most efficient overal bandwidth, with priority to incoming data?

Today, my point of view is that the most consuming operation is the unmarshalling/marshalling process. Thus, I would fire goroutine like this, after the reception of any events (that doesn't require ACK):

```
[...]
var rcvBuffer []byte
for {
   err := evt.Receive(ctx, rcvBuffer)
   go convertAndPush(rcvBuffer)
}

[...]
func convertAndPush(rcvBuffer []byte) {
   // unmarshall rcvBuffer
   // control
   // marshall to JSONpack
   JSONpack := json.Marshal(rcvBuffer)
   // fan out to another goroutine communicating with other services...
   pushch <- JSONpack
}
```

My focus is on receiving packets, not blocking CPU because of IO requests (either in- or out- ones), and not blocking IO because of CPU most costly operations of my application.

Is that way to design the application correct? What could I be missing?

btw, *Message reception function doesn't trigger goroutine.*

Comment: I don't think there's a generic answer to this, since this is a systems question and depends on a lot of details, especially around rate-limiting and overload management, but also about specifics of traffic patterns and your objectives for performance. Try something simple, and figure out what are the problems, and how to measure and visualize the performance characteristics of your solution, and go from there.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Indeed, I was looking for a kind of 'standard' pattern or a 'everybody uses this' strategy. Indeed, metrics is a key for fine-tuning in the end.

Answer (score 0):

+1 with Paul Hankin's approach.

In my experiences it's also best practice to bound concurrency of `convertAndPush`.  This can trivially be done using a semaphore or channels and a worker pool pattern.  This also provides a variable to toggle during load tests (worker pool size).

If the goal is to receive packets as fast as possible a channel/worker pool pattern might be better because it can be configured with a channel size to buffer requests and keep the read path low throughput.  Compared to a semaphore which would block the read path when it is at capacity.